# What is the difference between "Whatever/What ever happened to Sandra?" and "What happened to Sandra?"

Tags: phrases

Sandra's been missing for a while, so we ask:

```
Whatever/What ever happened to Sandra?
What happened to Sandra?
```

Is there any difference between these two questions and the situation to ask them in?

Comment: You may also want to add "What ever happened to Sandra?" to your question.  Which is likely what you really want to know about.

Comment: @Jim: Certainly *what ever* and *whatever* are not the same, but the question is *whatever*, as in the comedy *Whatever happened to the Likely Lads?*

Comment: Well now the question is for all three variants :D

Comment: What's the difference between _I have not been there_ and _I have not ever been there_? The difference is that _ever_ is an unnecessary qualification, which calls attention to itself and therefore can be interpreted as possibly expressing more anxiety in the speaker's motivation for asking about Sandra's whereabouts, or (in the example I gave) denying that I have been there.

Comment: So use of the word "ever" amplifies the uncertainty in the question? Or is it plain wrong to use it?

Comment: No. That's not what I said. And nothing can be "plain wrong"; don't be silly and don't jump to conclusions. **Unnecessary** use of _ever_ has come to be symptomatic of emotional expression in some contexts -- usually supported by intonation changes -- but the precise emotional details are determined in context, and are all supplied by the addressee's imagination in any event. This is not a code book; this is a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the offered usage, the term *[whatever](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/whatever)* means

> Used for emphasis instead of “what” in questions, typically expressing surprise or confusion:
>   whatever is the matter? *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

In addition to emphasis, it is different in connotation from *what*.

*Whatever happened to Sandra* suggests that the speaker has lost track of Sandra for some period of time and is inquiring about Sandra's broad state of being/relationship to the speaker or listener.

The sentence *What happened to Sandra* is much less specific. It could mean the same as *Whatever ...* but is more likely to refer to a specific incident, rather than a general state of being.

The difference between *whatever* and *what* seems to be the subject of an ongoing semantic (or orthographic) argument. See, for example, this [usage discussion](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=whatever) at American Heritage Dictionary.